# Changing firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an android project which is connected to a firebase database, is there any way that I can unlink my project from current database and connect my app to a new firebase database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you meant to link your android project to a ***different*** firebase project, then of course you can. 
At the android side the "connection" is merely a json file stored at
`yourProject/app/google-services.json`. 
You can simply replace it with another file that you may download from the settings page of your new firebase project.